# Mongoose, aggregate query with $lookup return null?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

varyantalt  Model:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const varyantaltSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
  },
  varyantid: {
    type: String
  },
  altvaryantname: {
    type: String
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("varyantalt", varyantaltSchema, "varyantalt");
```

varyant model:

```js
const varyantSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
  },
  stokid: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
  },
  varyantname: {
    type: String
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("varyant", varyantSchema, "varyant");
```

varyant collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e32286c34fb7322bdd566ed"),
    "stokid": ObjectId("5e28b4a2a1d9692b29a65b24"),
    "varyantname": "RENK"
}
```

altvaryant collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e3228df34fb7322bdd566f5"),
    "varyantid": "5e32286c34fb7322bdd566ed",
    "altvaryantname": "KIRMIZI",
    "vars": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5e35b1e410fce83f3370cd0a"),
            "images": {
                "imageurl": "http://",
                "_id": ObjectId("5e35b1e410fce83f3370cd0b"),
                "filename": "5320_7d93",
                "path": "https://res",
                "publicid": "panel"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e3359e6fa4c5e4bd9112fb6"),
    "varyantid": "5e32286c34fb7322bdd566ed",
    "altvaryantname": "SARI",
    "vars": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5e35b1f610fce83f3370cd0d"),
            "images": {
                "imageurl": "http://",
                "_id": ObjectId("5e35b1f610fce83f3370cd0e"),
                "filename": "veli-fidan-1LT-2-450x450",
                "path": "https://",
                "publicid": "panel"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e335b64fa4c5e4bd9112fc9"),
    "varyantid": "5e32286c34fb7322bdd566ed",
    "altvaryantname": "YEŞİL",
    "vars": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5e35b20010fce83f3370cd10"),
            "images": {
                "imageurl": "http://",
                "_id": ObjectId("5e35b20010fce83f3370cd11"),
                "filename": "maxresdefault-29-450x450",
                "path": "https://",
                "publicid": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Query:

```js
varyant
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        stokid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5e28b4a2a1d9692b29a65b24")
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "varyantalt",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "varyantid",
        as: "vars"
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$vars" }
  ])
  .exec((err, locations) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("res::", locations);
  });
```

I am trying to get results with `$aggregate` and `$lookup` query with mongoose
Why is my query returning empty? I couldn't find the problem.

Under `$lookup` operator `from: 'varyantalt'` I do not understand exactly whether it takes a blank value. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `varyantaltSchema` schema, `varyantid` is defined as String, but it must be `Schema.ObjectId`.

They must be same because  [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) performs an equality match on the foreignField to the localField from the input documents

If you save your varyandid as Object id aggregate will work.